# How can I get the audio level of microphone in C#/wpf?

Tags: c#, audio, usb, naudio, microphone

I've been testing NAudio (for some 5 hours), but I can't get any of the examples to compile and the documentation for it is more or less non-existent. I was able to get the level of the MS Sound Mapper, but when I tried using other WaveIn devices, such as my USB Audio Device, Lexicon Alpha, there's no input.

I was trying to find other libraries that could help me out, but there's nothing really out there. I only need the input level from my microphone and that's it.

Conversely, I was able to get the mic level in 5 minutes by using python-sounddevice, but I'd really like to use C#/WPF for this project. I find it hard to believe that this is simply impossible to do.

Any suggestions as to how to approach this problem?

Comment: "..the documentation for it is more or less non-existent" Have you looked at [this github folder](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/Docs)? And [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RecordingLevelMeter.md) is the documentation for quote "represent the current audio input level coming from a recording device". Isn't that exactly what you need? Also if you have tried anything unsuccessfully (it looks like you have) please consider adding the code to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Joelius. Yes, I've browsed what documentation there is. And  I tried that documentation for getting the input from a recording device. The first line of that example raises an error "'WaveInEvent' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments". So, I really don't know what to do about that.

Comment: So, I can figure out how to set the device number, despite the outdated instructions, but then another problem arises, when I start to follow the rest of it. The writer left out a lot of the important steps from the article because they are presumably covered somewhere else. But somewhere else they are used in a completely different function. I assume that the 'isRecording' boolean can be received from some NAudio method, but I couldn't tell you which one. Setting up a WaveFileWriter isn't covered in the article, and I don't want to write files. These outdated half-guides are just confusing.

Comment: You can get Microphone volume with native APIs/interfaces like Mixer APIs or Core Audio APIs. I tested Core Audio on Windows 10 (**IAudioEndpointVolume**) and it works fine (C# with P/Invoke)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Castorix. The examples I found that are using that interface are a bit advanced for me, but I suppose it's doesn't hurt giving it a go.

Comment: If you cannot make it work, I can post the test I did : the code is simple (loop on **IMMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints** to get the Microphone and the volume), but there are a lot of declarations for P/Invoke...